# How to add CAPTCHA in sign up and sign in policies in Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I searched in google for how to add CAPTCHA in b2c signup policy. but not getting any article so for. Is there a way to add CAPTCHA inside sign-up and sign-in process of Azure B2C? or any workaround

Comment: Why there is down point. my question is not valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, because Azure AD B2C doesn't allow custom or third-party JavaScript, which is required for CAPTCHA, then this isn't possible.

It will be possible when [Azure AD B2C does support Javascript](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15493536-add-support-for-javascript-inside-the-custom-ui-br).

The current alternative is to verify the email address for a new user during sign-up.